# layoutroot can't be resolved

Tags: java, android, android-layout, screenshot

I'm a newbie in android java programming, and I have a code to take a screenshot:

```
View content = findViewById(R.id.layoutroot); //it gives the "layoutroot cannot be resolved or is not a field" error
content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);         
Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.png");
            try 
            {
                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
                ostream.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

it gives the error:

> "layoutroot cannot be resolved or is not a field"

I don't know if I have to define "layoutroot", just don't know!
could anyone help me to solve this problem? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo, when you have:

```
View content = findViewById(R.id.layouroot);
```

You are missing a 't', it should be:

```
View content = findViewById(R.id.layoutroot);
```

Comment: I have already add the missing "t" but it still gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

Check, **if you have imported** `android.R`

**than Remove following import**

```
import android.R;
```

**it should be:**

```
import your.application.packagename.R;
```

**Edit**

**you will also have to define** `layoutroot`

Comment: I don't have that import. But I don't have layoutroot defined anywhere, I have buttons and listviews, but not layoutroot. do I have to define it?